# What is a good design for a container, assignment and items

Tags: design, design-patterns, database-design, ruby-on-rails, orm

```
    ------------- 1    * -------------- *       1 --------
    | Container |--------| Assignment |-----------| User |
    -------------        --------------           --------
          ^                     ^
          |                     |
      ----------            -------------
      |        |            |           |
---------- ----------  ---------- ---------------
| Flight | | Dinner |  | Booking| | Reservation |
---------- ----------  ---------- ---------------
```

This problem is one that I've stumbled upon in several different occasions but never found an elegant solution for:

In my system model (in rails), which maps to the database, I need to have `Users` that can be added to `Containers` through `Assignments`.

Now, there can be many things that can be containers:

- A `Flight` is a `Container`. It can hold `Users`. In such a case the concrete `Assignment` is a `Booking`.
- A `Dinner` is a `Container`. It can hold `Users`. In such a case the concrete `Assignment` is a `Reservation`.
- And many more. You get my point.

So I have Abstract notions of `Container` and `Assignment`. `Containers` hold `Assignments` and I also have concrete implementations of them, with each concrete implementation of `Container` matching a concrete implementation of `Assignment`. The straight forward design is as above. My main problem with it is that it doesn't express the relation between each concrete container and the concrete assignment.

Any ideas how to better design this?

Comment: Having something like flights and dinners in one and the same table looks rather ugly. Is there any serious relation between the two in your App other than the abstract notion of both of them being "containers"?

Comment: Offhand, it sounds to me like an `IContainer` (an interface, where you have different underlying implementations).

Comment: I'd give `Flight` a property `Bookings` and a property `Users`, where `Users` is a convenience feature.

I'd mostly abandon the notion of `Container` and `Assignment`, but if you really want you can use interfaces(`IContainer` with property `IEnumerable<IAssignment> Assignments` to represent them.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Polymorphic containers aren't exactly unprecedented.  You need them for an "activity list," for example, which can contain calendar, todo and project activities.

Comment: @thorsten müller I see your point. However, the main theme of my application is the assignment of users to various 'things'. These things may be very different in the real world (as flights and dinners), and the relations to the users may be different as well, but most of the logic of the system is related to this containment, so for the system, they are very similar. I wouldn't want to duplicate it for each.

Answer (score 1):

You've actually got a basic implementation of the [Bridge Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).

Where things break down is that a `Dinner` shouldn't contain a `Booking`. However, your model indicates that it can. From your comments, you indicated that there is a lot of shared logic in the `Container` class that works on a collection of `Assignment`s.

I am going to assume that the `Assignment` class performs its work using [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) to delegate implementation details to the sub-classes and that `Container` doesn't need to be aware of which `Assignment` type it is working with. In this case, the only concern is limiting what types of `Assignment`s can be associated with a `Container`.

In a typed language, you could create a "protected" `addAssignment` method in the `Container` class. Then in each `Container` subclass provide a public type-safe `addReservation` or `addBooking` method that just calls the protected `addAssignment`. You could enforce this will a runtime check in a dynamic language, but this seems like overkill.

Another solution is to recognize that both `Booking` and `Reservation` contain a single `User`. Technically you could create an "abstract" method in the `Container` called `addAssignment` accepting a `User` rather than an `Assignment`. The `Container` sub-classes then "override" the method by decorated the passed `User` object and adding to the underlying collection.

My point is that there are a lot of options, which might change on the way your objects are interacting. For instance, you could even pass an `AssignmentFactory` to the `Container` that moved the creation logic somewhere else. You really have to decide to what level of control you want over your code. With a dynamic language it is a little more difficult to make explicit. I hope at least some of my examples also demonstrated just how over-engineered a solution can be when you start being paranoid.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed suggestions. Putting the creation logic in the container class/subclass may help a bit. I agree to your point about over engineering things.